# stacking model returns only one sided regression

Tags: python, scikit-learn

My predict result should have both positive and negative value. I use two stages prediction. Here are the steps:

```
  1) split the data into 3 sets(training, test and out of sample)
  2) train different base regressors using training set data,
     the regressors are different types of trees, such as gradient boosting tree.
  3) use trained regressor to predict test set
  4) use the predicted output from step 3 to train svm to come
     up with the second level model. 
  5) use each regressor to predict out of sample data
  6) use step 5 output value as input to step 4 fitted model to
     predict final result on out of sample data.
```

In my response variable(prediction), I should have both positive and negative values, but in step 6 I only see all the prediction are positive values

```
 1)  Here is a sample of step 5, using only 3 base learners,
     obviously they have both positive and negative values from different learners:

    >>array([[  6.72144956e-04,   1.56136199e-03,   1.58553265e-04],
     [ -4.63248063e-04,   4.95401301e-04,   1.10566458e-04],
      ...
     [  1.48747688e-03,  -1.11622013e-03,  -7.57807887e-05]]
  2) output of step 6, here all the values are positive, buy real value
     obviously have both positive and negative.
     >> array([  4.56349996e-04,   4.43408819e-04, ...
            4.36207927e-04])
```

Here is the python code for blending models:

```
def fit(self):
  sub_models = self.models
  y_test_i = [] 
  for i in range(len(sub_models)):
    model = sub_models[i]
    y_test_i.append( model.predict(self.x_test))
    y_test_i = np.array(y_test_i).T
  parameters = {
      "kernel": "rbf",
      "C": 0.001,
      "gamma" : 0
  }
  self.blender = SVR(**parameters)
  self.blender.fit( y_test_i, self.y_test.values)

  def pred(self):
    y_oos_i = []
    for i in range(len(self.models)):
      model = self.models[i]
      y_oos_i.append( model.predict(self.x_oos))
    y_oos_i = np.array(y_oos_i).T
    y_pred = self.blender.predict(y_oos_i)
```

My question is how do I debug such situation? btw: I have around 800 data points for each set and around 20 features as step 2 input.

Comment: are you sure your train set contin neg and pos values?

Comment: Yes, you can take a look at my data output there. It definitely has +/- number.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably that your training data at one stage is all nonnegative

To debug, I would recommend counting the number of positives and negatives in each training and test set for every stage
(something like):

```
print "N nonnegatives: ", np.count_nonzero(Y_train >= 0)
print "N negatives: ", np.count_nonzero(Y_train < 0)
```

Particularly, it seems that the step 4 training or test data might be suspect.